# Is Ghast a boss?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

Ghasts are cool to me. I have asked a friend: is the Ghast a boss?

I need to know because I am getting Minecraft on Xbox 360.

Comment: "I'm aghast you would even ask!" says a nearby ghast with an excited grin. Everyone else rolls their eyes.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You are lucky there is no pun police on Arqade.

Comment: @Fredy31 if there were, it wouldn’t be arqade :) (quite literally, it would be named arcade instead)

Answer (score 4):

No, Ghasts are normal hostile mobs that live in the Nether.

They can spawn in basalt deltas, nether wastes, and soul sand valley biomes, so you can find more than one wandering around.

Answer (score 1):

They are definitely not a boss, though can be more tricky than your average zombie. Reason being is because they fly and their attacks hit rather hard. They also contain a unique mechanic which lets you deflect their attacks and shoot them back at them.

Comment: Did you finish writing your answer?

Comment: I removed the trailing sentence from your post. If you click the "Edit" button on your post, you'll be able to add your sentence back, and finish it off. Cheers!